# binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<_Kty,_Ty>'

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, const-correctness

I don't know where the error is coming from. It seems like I'm passing valid data into the [ ] operator.

```
template <class VertexType>
typename map< Vertex<VertexType>, int >::iterator Graph<VertexType>::findEdge( const VertexType& v, const VertexType& w ) const
{
    map<Vertex<VertexType>, int>::const_iterator iter = vertices[v].second.adjList.find(w);

    return iter;
}  // end findEdge
```

The error:

```
error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=unsigned int,
1>              _Ty=Vertex<unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(164): could be 'Vertex<VertexType> &std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](unsigned int &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              VertexType=unsigned int,
1>              _Kty=unsigned int,
1>              _Ty=Vertex<unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(209): or       'Vertex<VertexType> &std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](const unsigned int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              VertexType=unsigned int,
1>              _Kty=unsigned int,
1>              _Ty=Vertex<unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const std::map<_Kty,_Ty>, const unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=unsigned int,
1>              _Ty=Vertex<unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\user\desktop\cs m20a\topic g project 2\topic g project 2\graph.h(146) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree> Graph<VertexType>::findEdge(const VertexType &,const VertexType &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<Vertex<unsigned int>,int,std::less<Vertex<unsigned int>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const Vertex<unsigned int>,int>>,false>>,
1>              VertexType=unsigned int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\user\desktop\cs m20a\topic g project 2\topic g project 2\graph.h(52) : while compiling class template member function 'Graph<VertexType>::Graph(unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              VertexType=unsigned int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\user\desktop\cs m20a\topic g project 2\topic g project 2\topicg.cpp(17) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Graph<VertexType>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              VertexType=unsigned int
1>          ]
```

And the `Graph` class:

```
template <class VertexType>
class Graph
{
private:
     // list of all vertices in the graph. assumes non-duplicate data.
    map< VertexType, Vertex<VertexType> > vertices;

    const unsigned MAX_VERTICES;  // Maximum number of vertices the graph can hold.
    unsigned numVertices;         /** Current number of vertices in the graph. */
    unsigned numEdges;            /** Number of edges in the graph. */

    typename map< Vertex<VertexType>, int >::iterator findEdge( const VertexType& v, const VertexType& w ) const;  

public:
   Graph( unsigned max );

   unsigned getNumVertices() const;
   unsigned getMaxNumVertices() const;
   unsigned getNumEdges() const;
   int getWeight( const VertexType& v, const VertexType& w ) const;

   Graph<VertexType>& addVertex( const VertexType& newValue );
   Graph<VertexType>& addEdge( const VertexType& v, const VertexType& w, int weight );
   void removeEdge( const VertexType& v, const VertexType& w );
   void BFS( const VertexType& v ) const;
   void display() const;
}; // end Graph
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`operator[]` can only be called on a non-`const` map.

If the key doesn't exist, it will be inserted with a default constructed value.

To get a const iterator, use `map::find`.

Comment: Another alternative would be `std::map::at`

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) has different semantics in that it throws an exception if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: Sounds like a glaring omission to me

Comment: @TomLint what do you think is missing?

Comment: @PeterWood A const operator[] obviously

Comment: @TomLint how would it handle missing keys?

Comment: @PeterWood Via an exception, just like `std::map::at`

Comment: @TomLint but then you have two different calling conventions. `[]` would throw on `const` maps. What if you want it to throw on non-`const` maps?

Comment: @PeterWood It should throw on both; attempting to access a non-existing value through operator[] is an error case, and "If the key doesn't exist, it will be inserted with a default constructed value." is broken behavior, in my opinion, as it hides the aforementioned error condition.

Comment: @TomLint what would the syntax be to update a value, or to create a new value?

Comment: @PeterWood Syntax for update value would be the same as it is now, create new value should be explicit.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando how do you know whether you're updating or adding a new value? Querying for existence then modifying if it exists, or creating a new value would require error handling every time you want to want to update a value. Creating new values would take 2 lookups as they would be separate user operations and would be inefficient.

Comment: @PeterWood the point is that accessing non-existing value should throw (or indicate error in other way), but definitely NOT create default constructed value of a type. This is completely wrong behaviour. So, if there is such line of code: m_map[0] = 1;//<< we don't care if this is creation or update, but if we see line like const auto& v{m_map[1]};//<<here if we don't have a value at inx 1 we should get error.

Comment: Intuitively I would think that the operator[] would be used for reading values, not creating things (when missing). Too bad the architects made this choice.

Comment: @TomLint: "Via an exception, just like `std::map::at`". No, it should not even compile. And if `std::map::at`is trying to set a value on a const map, it also should not even compile.

Comment: @sergiol that is why you have both const and non-const operator[] implementations in a proper implementation.

Answer (score 5):

While not the case above, the same problem will occur if you use the [] operator in a const function.